# Vectorizing scipy norm.pdf

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

```
def predictDigit(img):

    prob = [0] * 10

    for digit in range(10):
        for pix in range(len(img)):
            std = pix_std[digit][pix]
            mean = pix_means[digit][pix]
            if std == 0:
                continue
            else:
                prob[digit] += np.log(norm.pdf(img[pix], mean, std))
        prob[digit] += np.log(digit_prob[digit])

    return np.argmax(prob)
```

I wrote this function to use it for implementing a Naive Bayes Classifier for digit classification. The idea is to go through all pixels of an input image and add the `np.log(norm.pdf(img[pix], mean, std))` to the `prob` and return the argmax of it at the end to label the digit of the input image.

However, this takes too long. I successfully vectorized getting the mean and std using:

`pix_means[digit] = np.mean(image_cluster[digit], axis = 0)
pix_std[digit] = np.std(image_cluster[digit], axis = 0)`

But, I am not sure if vectorization is possible with `norm.pdf`.

Please help.

**EDIT**

**Digit Prob**

```
digit_count = {}

for digit in y_train:
    if digit not in digit_count:
        digit_count[digit] = 1
    else:
        digit_count[digit] += 1

digit_prob = {}

for digit in range(10):
    digit_prob[digit] = digit_count[digit] / len(y_train)
```

**image_cluster**

```
image_cluster = {}

for image, digit in zip(x_train, y_train):
    if digit not in image_cluster:
        image_cluster[digit] = [image]
    else:
        image_cluster[digit].append(image)

pix_means = {}
pix_std = {}

# get mean and sd
for digit in range(10):
    pix_means[digit] = np.mean(image_cluster[digit], axis = 0)
    pix_std[digit] = np.std(image_cluster[digit], axis = 0)
```

Comment: Please show at least the shapes of the arrays that aren't defined in the function, or better yet, provide an actual MCVE. It's impossible to play with the code you've provided because so much information is missing.

Comment: You can vectorize the call you are interested in, but I can't tell you how based on what you provided.

Comment: @MadPhysicist The shape of the input `img` is a 1-d array with 784 elements (pixels). It can be resized later to be a `28x28` image, but in the function, it will just be a 1d `1x784` array with values.

Comment: What is image_cluster? Why not vectorize pix_means and pix_std completely?

Comment: What is digit_prob?

Comment: @MadPhysicist `image_cluster` is a cluster of images based on the digit. I needed that to vectorize using `np.mean` and `np.std`. And `digit_prob` is the probability of `digit` appearing in the training set.

Comment: Why did you make things indexed 0-9 into dictionaries?

Comment: @MadPhysicist To make it easily accessible by digit.

Comment: I see. For future reference, a list or an array can be thought of as a mapping that only allows integer keys. They are also ordered by key, so slicing means something, and arrays require a homogeneous type for the values.

Comment: What is y_train? I'm just asking for the shape, assuming it's an array.

Comment: @MadPhysicist `y_train` has a shape of (60000,) which is a `1x60000` array with labels of `x_train`

Comment: I'm getting the feeling that your whole program can be vectorized into just a few lines of numpy.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I am new to this kind of stuff. It would be great if you can show me how it could work.

Comment: I'll give it a shot

Comment: @MadPhysicist Any luck?

Comment: Sorry, I passed out and went to sleep right after writing that :) I'll try again today.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Thank you so much

Comment: @MadPhysicist Sorry for bothering. Were you able to make some progress?

Comment: Sorry, not today. But I haven't forgotten about you.

Answer (score 0):

norm.pdf is vectorized right out the box!

> To compute the cdf at a number of points, we can pass a list or a numpy array.
>
> ```
>    norm.cdf([-1., 0, 1])
>    array([ 0.15865525,  0.5,  0.84134475])
>    import numpy as np
>    norm.cdf(np.array([-1., 0, 1]))
> ```

> ```
>    array([ 0.15865525,  0.5,  0.84134475])
> ```
>
> Thus, the basic methods, such as pdf, cdf, and so on, are vectorized.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/stats.html